# Remove CSS of WordPress admin bar

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In a WordPress blog I want to disable admin/logged users topbar.

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
function remove_admin_login_header() {
remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() {
show_admin_bar(false);
}
```

The code above removes the admin bar but it still prints the following CSS and I need to remove it because it is useless.

```
<style type='text/css'>#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings .ab-icon:before{content:'\f111';top:2px;color:rgba(240,245,250,.6)!important;}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings-default .ab-icon:before{top:0px;}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings .ab-icon.on:before{color:#00f200!important;}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings-default li,#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings-default a,#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings-default li:hover,#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-settings-default a:hover{border:1px solid transparent;}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-blocks .ab-icon:before{content:'\f135';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-positions .ab-icon:before{content:'\f207';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-positions-default .ab-icon:before{content:'\f522';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-tags .ab-icon:before{content:'\f475';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-no-insertion .ab-icon:before{content:'\f214';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-ad-blocking .ab-icon:before{content:'\f160';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-processing .ab-icon:before{content:'\f464';}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-positions span.up-icon{padding-top:2px;}#wp-admin-bar-ai-toolbar-positions .up-icon:before{font:400 20px/1 dashicons;}</style>
```

What PHP code or filter would you use to remove it?

NOTE: I want to remove CSS output, not hiding divs!

Comment: why are you concerned? Leave it there, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I've set a few plugins to hide the fact I'm using WordPress but these lines clearly show it's WordPress. Why should I serve many useless lines of code to my users? I like clean code.

Comment: I want to remove CSS output, not hiding divs

Comment: `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');` or `how_admin_bar(false);` into `functions.php`

Comment: It removes the bar but CSS is still there.

Comment: If you don't have many users, you could disable it in the dashboard for each user. This removes the bar and also the inline CSS.

Comment: https://themeisle.com/blog/hide-wordpress-admin-bar/#:~:text=You%20can%20hide%20the%20admin,site%20option%20and%20save%20changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!function_exists('disableAdminBar')) {

        function disableAdminBar(){

        remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 ); // for the admin page
        remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 ); // for the front end

        function remove_admin_bar_style_backend() {  // css override for the admin page
          echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar #adminmenu { padding-top: 0px !important; }</style>';
        }

        add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend');

        function remove_admin_bar_style_frontend() { // css override for the frontend
          echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
          html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
          * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
          </style>';
        }

        add_filter('wp_head','remove_admin_bar_style_frontend', 99);

      }

    }

    // add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend'); // Original version
    add_action('init','disableAdminBar'); // New version

 //JUST PAST THIS function.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to remove that inline css. Copy this to your functions.php

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```